# JavaScript RegEx to get test spec

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a need to get the current test spec my caret is in when using Jasmine. So if I have a spec like:

```
it("should do something", function() {
    var foo = 'bar';

    expect(foo).toEqual('bar');
});
```

and I have my caret in the blank line and I click some button in a UI, it should go back from the caret to find the spec. So it goes to the `var foo = 'bar';` line and detects it's not a match so goes to the next which has `it()` and therefore finds that line to be the spec. So going back line by line I can do but detecting if it's the line with the `it()` in it is what I need help with.

My end case will be detecting if the `function()` being passed as the 2nd arg has an argument in it or not. If it doesn't then I need to add one in there. So since the above snippet doesn't have an argument in the `function()` then I need to add one so that it looks like:

```
it("should do something", function(done) {
    var foo = 'bar';

    expect(foo).toEqual('bar');
});
```

Notice the `done` now in the `function()`. Also, the `"should do something"` can be double quotes or single quotes and can contain any legal JavaScript character in it.

As a test, I used this RegEx:

```
/^\s*it\((?:"|')[\w\s]+(?:"|'), function\((?:\w+)?\) {/
```

And it works for my simple tests but it feels incomplete especially in the `"should do something"` detection part.

Comment: If the string contains escaped quotes like `"\""`, your regex won't work. And you should check the closing quote corresponds to the opening one.

Comment: I think you can safely use [`^\s*it\([^,]*(?:,(?!\s*function\()[^,]*)*,\s*function\(\w*\)\s*{`](https://regex101.com/r/yP0nW6/1). It matches `it(` followed by anything that is not `, function(`, and then `, function(...) {`.

Comment: @stribizhev seems to be working quite well and saw some other improvements you made. May want to move this comment out to be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can safely use a regex that is based on the [unroll-the-loop method](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop):

```
^\s*it\([^,]*(?:,(?!\s*function\()[^,]*)*,\s*function\(\w*\)\s*{
```

It matches `it(` at the beginning of a string, followed by anything that is not `, function(` and then `, function(...) {`. A synonym of a `^\s*it\([\s\S]*?,\s*function\(\w*\)\s*{`, but a much more efficient expression.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP0nW6/1)

Now, if you need to match such signatures without any text inside `function()`, you can use capturing groups around the subpatterns you want to keep and that you can later reference as `$1` and `$2`:

```js
var re = /^(\s*it\([^,]*(?:,(?!\s*function\()[^,]*)*,\s*function\()(\)\s*{)/; 
var str = 'it("should do something", function() {\n    var foo = \'bar\';\n\n    expect(foo).toEqual(\'bar\');\n});';
var subst = '$1done$2'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.write(result);
```

If you really can have such wierd strings as Oriol suggests, use

```
^\s*it\((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'),\s*function\(\w*\)\s*{
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP0nW6/3)

It will match

```
it(",function(){", function() {
it(',function(){', function() {
```

Comment: `it(",function(){", function() {` breaks it.

Comment: Where did you get this string out? It is not what OP has. Here is a regex for your weird one: [`^\s*it\("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*",\s*function\(\w*\)\s*{`](https://regex101.com/r/yP0nW6/2)

Comment: OP says the string can contain any legal JavaScript character. I choose `",function(){"`.

Comment: Updated to match this stuff.